# How can I reference the Window object in a function without passing it as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, window, pysimplegui

I have a main Window object in my script and I want to reference the Window object in a function without having to pass the Window object as a parameter.

How can I reference my Window object ?

Regards,
Mike

I can make it works passing the reference as an argument like in :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def func1(msg,window):
    for i in range (10):
        log = msg + str(i)
        update_log(log,window)
    return
def update_log(msg,window):
    print(msg)
    window.Element('_LOGWINDOW_').update(msg + '\n', append=True)

mylog = [sg.Multiline(size=(20, 15), enable_events=True, horizontal_scroll=True, key='_LOGWINDOW_',autoscroll=True, default_text='')]
layout =[ [mylog
        ,sg.Button('Run',key='_RUN_')]]
window = sg.Window('Test',layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, '_CLOSE_'):
        break
    if event == '_RUN_':
        func1('Hello world',window)

window.close()
```

But I don't want to pass the reference as an argument because my function will call another function where I want to reference the Window object.

Comment: this appears to be working (it logs a bunch of messages to the window),  what are you expecting ?

Comment: Remove this argument directly. It will be a global variable if you don't assign value to it, or you can add statement `global window`.

Comment: I could declare my window object as global but I don't want to mess with global variables because I have many different windows to reference...